# How can I delete/uninstall everything? I want it to be the same as the time that hadn't started react native learning

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have been learning `react-native` for some weeks. Now I got stuck somewhere and what to start everything from the very beginning. so I need to uninstall everything like react, `react native`, `redux`, `thunk` and etc. I have `node.js`. How can I delete/uninstall everything? I want it to be the same as the time that hadn't started `react-native` learning.

Comment: How did you install node? are you using NVM? those packages should have been installed on a per-project basis (if done correctly) so you can just ```rm -rf node_modules``` in your projects directory. If you installed them globally, you will find an .npm folder with said packages (usually at your home folder) .... AHH windows

Comment: If it is a Windows system then use the normal uninstall procedure. This may not completely clean it out however. If it is a Linux based system, then kill the offending directories.

Comment: @archae0pteryx i just downloded from node.js page. could you please add more details and post it as an answer? thanks

Comment: are you on windows or mac or linux

Comment: @archae0pteryx windows 7

Answer (score 0):

On windows all you need to do is go into your control panel > add remove programs and features > find node.js and uninstall. Poof! This will remove node... as far as your npm packages go, it looks like they are stored by default in \HOME\AppData\Roaming\npm. Just delete this folder to get rid of global packages. If you have a project where you installed non global (local) project packages then you need to delete the node_modules folder in that projects folder

Comment: so will everything that i install via node (for instance redux, recat-native and etc) be gone too after uninstaling node from control panel?

Comment: I just double checked and updated my answer. looks like they are all stored in your AppData\Roaming\npm folder which is in your home folder and might be hidden...

Comment: Then the answer is yes. That will all be gone.